# steps to recognize detected faces using opencv library

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am using OpenCV library and I can detect multiple faces in a video file or using a webcam. Now, I want to recognize those faces.

If any one guide me step by step means what should I do after detecting faces,it will be great for me. I am using C and C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

@KISHAN, You may follow [a tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d86/tutorial_dnn_javascript.html) with an example of using [OpenFace](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface) deep learning network. It takes a `96x96` image of human's face and returns `128`-dimensional unit vector called embedding vector. You may match two persons by dot product of these embeddings. So this neural network maps faces to multidimensional unit sphere where similar faces are mapped to the closer points.

NOTE: there is a live demo which downloads models (~35MB) if you pressed a `Start` button.